# Is there a word to describe the feelings of a flatterer?

Tags: single-word-requests

[Flattery](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flattery) is described as "the act or practice of flattering." So John praises Mary. Mary feels good about John's praise, but John also feels good about the praise he gives to Mary. What is a word to describe John's feelings?

Mary is *flattered* by John's praise. John is ________ by his praise of Mary.

A word that goes in the right direction is "fulfilled." That is, "John is fulfilled by his praise of Mary," but I want a stronger, more "positive" word. John sincerely believes what he says in praising Mary, and is in turn flattered when a third party praises his praise of Mary.

Comment: @StoneyB: I have gotten two useful answers so far, both of which I have upvoted. But I did add a last line to more narrowly specify the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John is **gratified** by his praise of Mary.

From [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gratify):

> 2: to be a source of or give pleasure or satisfaction to
>   //it *gratified* him to have his wife wear jewels

Comment: May I please have a comment from the down-voters?  I admit this is terse, but it provides a source and a definition.

Answer (score -1):

I’d use, not an adjective, but a noun, such as “John’s effusiveness /ebullience /adulation /encomium /praise brought him joy.

Comment: A useful suggestion. Upvoted by me (although not yet by others).